# Using Max(boolean) in a case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, boolean-logic

I am made a temp table of accounts in a database with booleans that provide insight about the accounts. Some customers have multiple accounts so I am grouping them together and was trying to look at the MAX(Boolean) to set a status field.

My query kinda looks like:

```
with t as (Select lngCustomerNumber, 
           Case
             When 'Criteria for being Active' Then 1
           End as blnActive, 
            Case 
            When 'Criteria for unexpired' Then 1
           End as blnUnexpired
From AccountTable) 
Select t.CustomerNumber, 
        Case 
           When Max(t.blnActive) = 1 
           AND  Max(t.blnUnexpired) = 1 Then 'Active/Unexpired' 
           When Max(t.blnActive) = 1 
           AND  Max(t.blnUnexpired) = 0 Then 'Active/Expired' 
           When Max(t.blnActive) = 0 
           AND  Max(t.blnUnexpired) = 1 Then 'Inactive/Unexpired' 
           When Max(t.blnActive) = 0 
           AND  Max(t.blnUnexpired) = 0 Then 'Inactive/Expired'
    End As strLicenseStatus
From T
Group By t.CustomerNumber
```

Anything where it checks if the Max(Boolean) = 1 will calc to True correctly, but if I do Max(Boolean) = 0 or Max(Boolean) <> 1 then it does not calc to True when it should.
I have tested by just looking at the grouped Temp Table with each boolean bringing back its Max() value and the ones that should be 0 are coming back as 0.

As a workaround, I have tried

```
Where t.CustomerNumber  NOT IN  (SELECT t2.CustomerNumber

            FROM    t t2 

            WHERE   t2.blnUnexpired    = 1 
            AND t2.CustomerNumber    = t.CustomerNumber  )
```

And that does give me the results that I am looking for but I have millions of rows coming back so it has been timing out after many hours, where the previous method was able to run in less than an hour.

I have some other data in my query, the one presented is a much smaller version used to highlight my issue.

Any recommendations on how I can make this work?
Thank you.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Boolean values are TRUE, FALSE, and perhaps UNKNOWN/null, according to ANSI SQL. And TRUE > FALSE.

Comment: Apologies, I am using Oracle. I have edited and added the tag.

Comment: Instead of "My Query kinda looks like ...", could you come up with a real, reproducible example that mimics the problem you are encountering ? That makes it a lot easier to help you with the issue.

Comment: I don't see any Boolean values in your query. Oracle SQL doesn't have a Boolean. I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining your `blnActive` and `blnUnexpired` cases, you only have the "1" case defined, which means if it doesn't meet these criteria, it will be null. Try adding `else 0` to each case:

```
with t as (Select lngCustomerNumber, 
           Case
             When 'Criteria for being Active' Then 1
             Else 0
           End as blnActive, 
            Case 
              When 'Criteria for unexpired' Then 1
              Else 0
           End as blnUnexpired
From AccountTable)
```